# Export / import const in typescript 3

Tags: typescript

Here is my first part code in Hello.tsx  :

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface HelloProps { compiler: string; framework: string; }
const Hello = (props: HelloProps) => <h1>Hello from {props.compiler} and {props.framework}!</h1>;

export default Hello;
```

And i'am trying to import it in index.tsx :

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Hello } from "./components/Hello";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello compiler="TypeScript" framework="React" />,
    document.getElementById("example")
);
```

But i have a :

> Module '"./components/Hello"' has no exported member 'Hello'.ts(2305)

Error.

Comment: loose the `default` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are exporting `Hello` as the default export but importing it as a named export.

Instead, either import it as a default export with this line:

```
import Hello from "./components/Hello";
```

or export it as a named export by getting rid of the `export default Hello;` and exporting it like this:

```
export const Hello = (props: HelloProps) => <h1>Hello from {props.compiler} and {props.framework}!</h1>;
```